# pass title of page into url

Tags: python, django, django-views

Using Django I am trying to pass the title of the current page into a dynamic URL but I keep getting errors, the title of the page is also produced dynamically from other views.py functions.

**Error**

> exception type:  TypeError

> exception value:  edit_page() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'

**urls.py**

```
 path("wiki/edit/<str:title>", views.edit_page, name="edit")
```

**HTML file**

```
{% block title %} {{ title }} {% endblock %} 

{% block body %} 
<a class="page-link" href="{% url 'wiki:edit' page=title %}">edit page</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_page(request, page):
page_request = page
if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit_page.html", {
        "form": form,
        "page": page_request
    })
```

Comment: What error you have got? Add the error traceback

Comment: Updated it with the error traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your parameter of `edit_page(...)` function to

```
def edit_page(request, title):
    page_request = title
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain why that happened? Was the syntax wrong?

Comment: The view function was expecting a parameter named ***`title`*** and you were sent a parameter named ***`page`***

Comment: Could you Upvote on the answer if it was helpful? @Gerald-x